# how to use combo box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed `AjaxControlToolkit` package and added those `.dll` files, also added them to reference. The problem is when I use `ComboBox` in the code it is showing error

> Could not find schema information for the element
>   AjaxControlToolkit
>   error;
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=17.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you checked this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548083/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-ajaxcontroltoolkit

Comment: Your ajax Toolkit version is different with current version.